# Creating a chain rule from a series of similar expressions

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm doing some calculations on trial and error basis although I'm using the same formula in each step:

```
c1 = c0 - c0*R + F
c2 = c1 - c1*R + F
c3 = c2 - c2*R + F
```

Given: c0 = 100, c3 = 21.3, and F = 5. I need to figure out the value of R. In this case R=0.5.

```
c1 = 100 - 100*0.5 + 5 = 55
c2 = 55- 55*0.5 + 5 = 32.5
c3 = 32.5 - 32.5*0.5 + 5 = 21.3
```

But I have to solve it for a large number of C0 and C3 values. It is tedious to accomplish it on a trial and error basis in an excel worksheet. More importantly if using the same equation I was given c1 and c100 it is even more complicated! Is there any way to simplify a set of such equations to one since the formula remains the same and there is only one variable that updates in each step of my calculation?

Comment: Using your answer I get $c_2$ is 32.5 not $c_3$. Can you please check which you mean.

Comment: I corrected the mistake, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to original question:

Lets first rewriting them using brackets to factorise:

$$\color{blue}{c_1=c_0(1-R)+F}$$
$$\color{red}{c_2=c_1(1-R)+F}$$
$$c_3=c_2(1-R)+F$$
It will be neater throughout the calculations to keep the $(1-R)$ together so we'll look at how to find $(1-R)$ from which $R$ can be found easily.100

You can combine your equations into one using substitution:

$$c_3=(\color{red}{(c_1(1-R)+F)}(1-R)+F$$
$$c_3=(\color{red}{(\color{blue}{(c_0(1-R)+F)}(1-R)+F)}(1-R)+F$$
Expanding gives:
$$c_3=c_0(1-R)^3+F(1-R)+F(1-R)+F$$
Putting in $c_0$, $c_3$ and $F$ gives:
$$21.25=100(1-R)^3+5(1-R)^2+5(1-R)+5$$
Solving the cubic gives:
$$(1-R)=0.5$$
$$R=0.5$$

Answer to extended part:

(*this is a good solution but what if I have a longer series; e.g. given c1=67, c12= 97, and F=5?*)

From the above we can see a longer series will be in the form:

$$c_n=c_0(1-R)^n+F(1-R)^{n-1}+F(1-r)^{n-2}+...+F(1-R)^2+F(1-R)+F$$

On the right hand side the terms (from second onwards) form a GP.

$$c_n=c_0(1-R)^n+\frac{F(1-(1-R)^n)}{R}$$
$$0=c_0R(1-R)^n-F(1-R)^n-c_nR+F$$
$$0=c_0(-(1-R)+1)(1-R)^n-F(1-R)^n-c_n(-(1-R)+1)+F$$
$$0=-c_0(1-R)^{n+1}+C_0(1-R)^n-F(1-R)^n+c_n(1-R)-c_n+F$$
$$0=c_0(1-R)^{n+1}+(F-C_0)(1-R)^n-c_n(1-R)-+c_n+F$$
This is a polynomial of degree $n$ in terms of $(1-R)$. For most $n$ you will need numerical solutions. You could build the equation in excel and use trial and error as before. You could also use Excel's "Goal Seek" option.

Comment: this is a good solution but what if I have a longer series; e.g. given c1=67, c12= 97, and F=5?